# Check php errors log in my EC2 Instance running Amazon Linux

Tags: php, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Iv have been trying to find a way on how to find where my php errors log file is stored in. I am using an EC2 Instance, in Amazon AWS running Amazon Linux. Usually, when using MAMP, I get some PHP Warnings and Notices I can see in a php_log file.

I have been looking for the file, and still no luck finding it.

Do you know where I can find the error log (file)?

Thanks a lot!

Cheers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Depending what configuration you use, the errors will either go into the web server error log file, or it will be stored in `/var/log/php-fpm/5.6/` (assuming you are using 5.6)

Comment: Where would the web server error log file would be? Do you happen to know?

Comment: Most applications put logs in `/var/log`. With both apache and nginx you can tell it to store logs elsewhere, but if you haven't done that you should find them in `/var/log/httpd` or `/var/log/nginx`

Comment: Thanks! I could find it under `/var/log/httpd`

Comment: What do I do if I don't have a php-fpm folder?

Answer (score 15):

It is in /var/log/httpd/error_log

To debug and see log changes you can do

```
tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log
```

Comment: this works on my end, my current environment is ec2 linux ami

Comment: What do I do if my httpd folder is empty?

Comment: It says permission denied when I try to access the /var/log/httpd/ folder

Comment: If you're getting "permission denied", then put `sudo` in front of the command: `tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log`