# phpMyAdmin not showing output for SQL query longer than 0.5s - no error, no results, just hides query box

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to run a query through the SQL tab in phpMyAdmin 5.2.0 on a local MariaDB 10.5.10 server, my PHP version is 8.1.14, and my box is an EC2 instance running Amazon Linux 2 and Apache 2.4.54 with PHP-FPM

I'm pasting the query `SELECT SLEEP(x)`, where `x >= 0.5`, in the query box of the SQL pane; or any query that takes longer than 0.5s to run

When I click *Go* a spinner appears for the relevant number of seconds and then the whole SQL pane goes blank except for a button that says *Show query box*

There are no errors visible, no JS errors if I inspect the page, and I can't find anything untoward in my server logs; `/var/log/httpd/*.log` or `/var/log/php-fpm/*.log`

If I run `SELECT SLEEP(y)` where `y <= 0.4`; or a query that takes less than 0.4s to run; everything appears to work as expected. All queries also run correctly if I run mysql from the command line

What's going on? Where should I look to debug this?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but I guess it's hard to help you. Can you say how you installed your environment? Is it xamp? If so, there is a php error log as well for mysql. I would advise you to look there :)

Comment: @Wimanicesir Thanks, it's a cloud server running an Amazon Linux 2 LAMP stack

Comment: Did you try this already? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36102721/check-php-errors-log-in-my-ec2-instance-running-amazon-linux

Comment: @Wimanicesir Yes, have updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting with different versions of phpMyAdmin I managed to get my hands on an error thrown for the 0.5s+ queries with phpMyAdmin 5.2.1

```
mysqli::real_connect(): Argument #5 ($port) must be of type ?int, string given
```

and it looks like there is an issue handling the default server's port value, in PHP 8.1 at least, or any falsey port value

Updating my `config.inc.php` with a line

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = 3306;
```

fixes the issue, as does any truey integer

I believe this is a bug, as I don't think the port is used when connecting via socket - so I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/18141) on the phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin github

I have no idea why this wasn't affecting the faster queries